# How to put URL string in json Viber API php

Tags: php, json, string, api, viber

I am a newbie developer trying to learn web development. I am currently working on this project where articles from a website get shared automatically to a viber public chat. I am facing this problem where I cannot put the URL in the media. I think this is because its json. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have included.

```
<?php

$Tid = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $Tid = $_GET['id'];
}

$url = 'https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/post';

$jsonData='{
 "auth_token":"4750f56f26a7d2ed-f6b44b76f03d039a-9601b6c9d0d46813",
 "from": "K9/C2Vz12r+afcwZaexiCg==",
 "type":"url",
 "media": "$thisID"
// I want to use $thisID as shown above. But when I
 do so this error appears [ {"status":3,"status_message":"'media' field value is not a valid url."} ] 

// When I use any full form url like https://google.com it works fine 
}';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: ___Small Point___ I see no `$thisID` ???

Comment: $thisID is not interpolated as a value because your jsonData string is in single quotes. Only double-quotes strings get [interpolated](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). And also because you don't have a variable called $thisID in your PHP anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean `$Tid` perhaps

Comment: Assuming `$thisID` is really `$Tid` then `"media": "' . $Tid . '"` would work as yu are using a single quoted literal

Comment: My bad. "media": "$thisID" is the correct way. I wrote it $thisID by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work as you are using a single quoted literal.

```
"media": "' . $thisID . '"
```

But you are always better to make a PHP array or Object and then use `json_encode()` to create the JSON String like this

```
$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->auth_token = "4750f56f26a7d2ed-f6b44b76f03d039a-9601b6c9d0d46813";
$obj->from = "K9/C2Vz12r+afcwZaexiCg==";
$obj->type = 'url';
$obj->media = $thisID;

$jsondata = json_encode($obj);
```

RESULT of `echo $jsondata;`

```
{"auth_token":"4750f56f26a7d2ed-f6b44b76f03d039a-9601b6c9d0d46813",
"from":"K9\/C2Vz12r+afcwZaexiCg==",
"type":"url",
"media":"-1"
}
```

Comment: I updated it using "media": "' . $Tid . '" 
and am getting this now {"status":3,"status_message":"missing mandatory field: media"}

Comment: You SHOW us you create a variable called `$Tid` and your code uses a variable called `$thisID` which you DONT show us in your code. Only you know which variable is the correct one to use here

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: does not fix the problem

Comment: Did you try using the second method I suggested?

Comment: Can you show me how you create the `$thisID` variable in your code

Comment: And Everyone who helped Thanks. The issue has been fixed now.